# Access denied service not found when integrating Auth0 and Hasura

Tags: reactjs, graphql, auth0, hasura

I'm following the Hasura's doc to integrate login feature with Auth0 using JWT. My GraphQL endpoint is working fine on the console. However, when I try to use the Auth0 SDK to implement a log in button, I'm getting the following error:

```
{error: "access_denied", error_description: "Service not found: https://mydomain.herokuapp.com/v1/graphql", state: "T3FEQUpFRXFqX1RqcGQwaXpms3lXeEM3Rk80ZaQtLUp3bWdRQmVzLXpRaA=="}
```

Is this something obvious that I'm missing?

Answer (score 8):

As far as I understand, this error message should happen if you define wrong audience (API identifier) parameter which does not exist in Auth0. Go to Auth0 Dashbord and create an API with API identifier `https://mydomain.herokuapp.com/v1/graphql`